# How can I implement this dataframe rolling assignment efficiently

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization, lambda, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe with 2 columns and I'd like to compute a sequence based on these two columns.

```
# branch below: recent mean of df.A is significantly GREATER than long time mean
if df['A'].rolling(10).mean()+df['A'].rolling(2).std() < df['A'].rolling(5).mean(): 
  df.x = -1 # df.x means the i-th element of df.x to be assigned
# branch below: recent mean of df.A is significantly LESS than long time mean
elif df['A'].rolling(10).mean()-df['A'].rolling(2).std() > df['A'].rolling(5).mean(): 
  df.x = 1
# branch below: df.B is greater than long time mean
elif (df['B'].shift(1) >= df['B'].shift(1).rolling(10).mean()):  
  df.x = 1
else:
  df.x = -1
```

I wonder how I can implement this assignment logic efficiently. If there was only 1 column, I can simply use apply+lambda expression. But it involves 2 columns and I could not figure it out.

**How to implement the above assignment logic efficiently?**

------------------ update --------------------------------

The following code achieves what I want.

```
np.where(df['A'].rolling(10).mean()+df['A'].rolling(2).std() < df['A'].rolling(5).mean(), -1,
     np.where(df['A'].rolling(10).mean()-df['A'].rolling(2).std() > df['A'].rolling(5).mean(), 1,
         np.where((df['B'] >= df['B'].rolling(10).mean()), 1, -1))
     )
```

I wonder if I can achieve it with better time efficiency and/or simpler code.

Comment: 1) simplify the branches, it seems like the output is only 1 or -1, so only one branch should be needed. 2) calculate the rolling means separately and store them somewhere instead of calculating them every time

Comment: take a look `numpy.select()` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19913845/15415267